# Buscar impresoras en red wifi (app android)

Tags: java, android

Que tal estoy desarrollando una aplicación y necesito mandar a imprimir pero no se como hacerlo, lo único que tengo, es como se genera el pdf que quiero imprimir pero necesito saber como mandarlo a imprimir pero seleccionando la impresora que este conectada por wifi, espero alguien sepa del tema y pueda ayudar, no pongo código porque no tengo nada relacionado a la impresión

Comment: Pero te imprime en la impresora por defecto? O no has intentado mandar a imprimir?

Comment: no :/, no me reconoce ninguna impresora :/,  se queda buscando pero no encuentra nada